# Is it "safe" to run a VSTS build agent locally (using PAT)?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm in the process of evaluating Visual Studio Team Services and am wondering if it's considered safe to run the build agent locally on a development machine (logged in to own account, vs. a separate machine/user for these purposes).

> Log on to the machine **using the account for which you've prepared permissions** as explained above.

Source: *[Download and configure the agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows#download-and-configure-the-agent)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it’s safe to use a build agent locally. And it’s both OK to use a build agent on a development machine or a separate machine.

**Build agent on a development machine**. It will consume the process of the local machine. If you run some large process consuming application, the agent may have an influence on it.

**Build agent on a separate machine**. For this way, you can manage the agent separately. It’s not necessary to use a separate account; you just need install the agent with your PAT (this is the only way to install an agent for VSTS).

So you can install an agent by the way you prefer. After configuring the agent, if you want to run the agent in service mode, before that, you can run it in interactive mode for the first time to check if it works normally, and then run the agent in service mode.

Comment: I'm assuming it would still be preferred to run the agent under a dedicated account with minimum privileges, is that correct? Or is it sort of moot at this point?

Comment: After playing with it for a little while longer, it actually makes a little more sense as to why you would run the build agent under your own domain account (still using PAT) as you can then configure your Build Definition to, for example, publish to a staging File Share that you have access to.

Comment: For the PAT used for build agent, you should at least select **Agent Pools (read, manage)**. Yes, it need use you own PAT since you want to configure your own build definitions.